# Writing python log files to logstash

Tags: python, docker, logstash

I am currently using the ELK stack as provided by Docker here:

```
https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk
```

To log in my python program, I am utilising the `python-logstash` library:

```
https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash
```

I am trying to write log to logstash (and view the subsequent data in Kibana) using the example at the `python-logstash` github page:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
LOGGER.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(127.0.0.1, 5000, version=1))
LOGGER.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
```

However, this is not writing any data to ElasticSearch, as verified via:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty=true
```

There are also no error or debug messages returned by the `python-logstash` library.

Can anybody point out what I am doing incorrectly?

My `logstash.conf` contains the following:

```
input {
tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `stdout{}` in your output section? Do you see your logs? If not, can you run `tcpdump port 5000` and check if you see the Python logs fly by?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find any solution or this?

Comment: I have the same problem :( To add some information: All containers are reachable, and if I manually post from the source to logstash it works

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
LOGGER.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(127.0.0.1, 5000, version=1))
```